# Readability vs Performance comparison

Tags: c#, .net, performance, readability

I was reviewing some of the code present in a project I'm working on and found things like these:

```
string personName = currentPerson.Name;
personModel.editPerson(idNr, personName);
```

The above is a simple example but it may as well be like below:

```
string idNr= currentPerson.IdNr;
string personName = currentPerson.Name;
string age = currentPerson.Age;
...
string editor = AuthenticatedUser.Name;

personModel.editPerson(idNr, personName, age, gender, whatever, nationality, ..., currentTime, editor, weather, windspeed, topScorer, teethAmount, ...);
```

**The question:**
Should the above be replaced by:

```
personModel.editPerson(currentPerson.idNr, currentPerson.Name);
```

and:

```
personModel.editPerson(currentPerson.idNr, currentPerson.Name, currentPerson.Age, currentPerson.Gender, currentPerson.Whatever, currentPerson.Nationality, ..., theTime.current, weather.Status, wind.speed, scorers.topScorer, mouth.teethAmount, ...);
```

respectively?

I think for readability, putting the values into variables is better but I'm guessing the performance will suffer (even if lightly). For the first example, where few parameters are used, the performance loss will be even lighter.

In our team, some people say it is better to have readability (specially for junior developers) at the low price of imperceptible performance losses, while others say that having too much of these variables that serve only the purpose of readability will in the end produce a loss of performance that may be noticed.

**EDIT**

I will try to explain what I meant with filling an object with values and distributing them afterwards with an example.

Imagine a form with multiple inputs:

```
public ActionResult _SavePerson(string id, string name, ...)
{
    personModel.editPerson(id, name, ...);
    ...
```

The editPerson method:

```
public void editPerson(string id, string name, ...)
{
    webService1.client client = new ....;
    webService1.personType pt = new ...;
    pt.name = name;
    pt.id = id;
    pt. ....;
    client.setPerson(pt);
    ....
}
```

If I was to pass an object as parameter:

```
public ActionResult _SavePerson(string id, string name, ...)
{
    Person person = new ...;
    person.id = id;
    person.name = name;
    personModel.editPerson(person);
    ...
```

The editPerson method:

```
public void editPerson(Person person)
{
    webService1.client client = new ....;
    webService1.personType pt = new ...;
    pt.name = person.name;
    pt.id = person.id;
    pt. ....;
    client.setPerson(pt);
    ....
}
```

Can you understand my doubt here?

Comment: I personally find it easier to read without the intermediate variables, as you can see exactly where the data is coming from, and where it's being passed. By adding the variables you can only see what it's being assigned from, or where it's being passed to, not both in a single line.

Comment: Performance will not suffer. But in *my* opinion, the readibility is better with passing the properties directly. Variables add extra unnecessary indirection. Also, try not to name methods that do wildly different things the same; I'm working with a codebase like that, and I can tell you that having 20 different methods named `editPerson` is going to make someone want to kill you :)

Comment: Why not `personModel.editPerson(currentPerson)` ?

Comment: I'd pass an object rather than have a method with 10+ parameters.

Comment: Based on your edit, I understand you have different objects depending the layer they are used on. In that case, that's what mappers are for! (and so you can use what everybody else advised, one entity per parameter).

Comment: Interesting question, but it would fit better at programmers.SE right?

Comment: @Alex, maybe you're right. I've seen a few here regarding comparison between readability and performance so I thought it would fit in SO. I also think that there's a thin line between Programmers.SE and StackOverflow

Comment: @Alex it has been already asked and answered over there: [Clean readable code vs fast hard to read code. When to cross the line?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/89620/31260)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring. If you have a group of parameters that naturally go together (person name, person age, etc) then group them into object and pass it as a single parameter.

Thus you already have such grouping of variables, you can just pass current person object:

```
personModel.editPerson(currentPerson);
```

As [Uncle Bob](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/) says, the best method for understanding and maintaining is method without parameters. One parameter is easy to understand. Two is harder. My rule of thumb - use no more than 3 parameters (of course, this is not always possible, but I try to follow that rule).

Note - if you have to pass lot of parameters somewhere, then probably you have data and logic living separately. Try to combine them and avoid passing data. E.g. instead of

```
 bankService.Charge(account.Id, account.Type, account.Balance, amount);
```

You can move this logic into account:

```
 account.Charge(amount);
```

Comment: But to pass an object as parameter, you will have to fill the objects properties first and then "distribute them" inside the method. Isn't that just "going to the same place using a diferent road"?

Comment: @chiapa what do you mean by filling object properties and distributing them? As I can see you already have currentPerson object with filled properties

Comment: @chiapa: You shouldn't create an object just to pass it in the method, but if you have one already, why bother passing the properties of that variable instead of the variable itself?

Comment: @chiapa model binder in ASP.NET MVC is able to build complex object from several parameters automatically

Comment: Yes Sergey, I am aware of that. But what of Asp.Net Web Forms development? My question is, having the scenarios I presented, which is better? Or, what should be favoured?

Comment: @chiapa almost always you have to deal with code you don't own - it might be infrastructure like ASP.NET Web Forms, external services, third party libraries or other modules of your application. You can't change that code and make it look clear. But code your own is a sandbox, which you can make clean and beautiful. Don't think how ASP.NET passes parameters. Focus on your code. Most expressive way is passing single object named `person`. So build it in 'buffer zone' which glues your code and external code. And pass  that object to your method.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, although this question can be somewhat opinion based, I'll mark your answer as correct. You are right when you say "focus on your code"

Answer (score 2):

If you won't use the variables again (`idNr`, `personName`, etc.), the compile will most likely omit those assignments and the performance will be the same.

On the discussion on which of them is most readable I can't say much: one likes the one, I like the other. There isn't a consensus on that and you as a development team should make that consensus for your own.

If you do care about readability, I would pass in as much as ready made objects as possible. That also keeps maintaining method signatures when adding or deleting a property, so maybe this is best (thanks [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470005/sergey-berezovskiy)):

```
personModel.editPerson(currentPerson);
```