# Shortening isNullOrEmpty and value assignment

Tags: c#, .net

I have a scenario where a form containing a checkbox is submitted, being its element name "someFlag".

If **checked**, it will come as "on".

If **not checked**, it will come as empty.

So I'm checking the emptyness of the `someFlag` string and assigning the value `1` if it is `on` and the value `0` if it is empty.

It works fine but, can this

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someFlag))
    someFlag= "0";
else
    someFlag= "1";
```

be written in a shorter way?

**EDIT**

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary) as I'm asking for a solution for a specific scenario, not a broad opinion based question such as the mentioned (it has been closed for that reason). I'm asking a question with two possible answers: *yes* or *no*.

Comment: If you were just checking for null, you could use coalesce: `someFlag = someFlag ?? "1";`

Comment: Shorter code is not always better code, prefer readability over one liners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To ternary or not to ternary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)

Comment: @DGibbs, that's an interesting point. Could you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073895/readability-vs-performance-comparison) please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator

```
someFlag = String.IsNullOrEmpty(someFlag) ? "0" : "1"
```

but I don't think you can shorten it further.

Comment: it is called the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx) (although it **is** a ternary operator)

Comment: @Default I didn't even know... I had always called it the ternary operator, and I hadn't ever thought that it isn't technically *the only possible* ternary operator (while at the same time, in programming, it *is* *The* ternary operator)